# react bootstrap accordion plus minus indicators issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap accordion to my project. I tried to add arrow-right and arrow-down icon for my accordion header. Its working well. But problem is when I click my first accordion header, second accordion icon also changed. please see the attached image

[image]

I tried to do this using below code.

```
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
     <Card>
                      <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle
                          as={Button}
                          variant="link"
                          eventKey="2"
                          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                        >
                          <span>
                            {open ? (
                              <i className="mdi  mdi-minus"></i>
                            ) : (
                              <i className="mdi  mdi-plus"></i>
                            )}
                          </span>
                          MATCH INVOICE LINES
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                      </Card.Header>

 <Card>
                      <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle
                          as={Button}
                          variant="link"
                          eventKey="2"
                          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                        >
                          <span>
                            {open ? (
                              <i className="mdi  mdi-minus"></i>
                            ) : (
                              <i className="mdi  mdi-plus"></i>
                            )}
                          </span>
                           LINES
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                      </Card.Header>
```

Above code is only the header sections. Other accordion functionalities working well. how I prevent this icon change issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are using a single state to handle both of your accordian headers. Try seperating the state logic. See

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

You have "One state to rule them all" :) Once you click on any of the header you are toggling the state logic in both the cases.

```
onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
```

Comment: Let me also see the best way to do this. I will have to run the code by installing you react-bootstrap package to do this. Either give me a moment or put your code on codesandbox for me to resolve this :) Ab kya kiya jayai janab. Rukiyai mai locally solve karta hun :) InshaAllah

Comment: Hey There . I am sharing with you the best resource to do this. Here is the link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/ . See whenever we use libraries, they usually have the best solutions for us. When you click on the link scroll down to Entire Header Clickable Section. Every Header has a property called eventKey="value", and that's what we can utilize to achieve our Task. let me also try. You also give it a try. May be you will come up with a fast and efficient solution :)

Comment: There are some Typos also in your code. </Card> not closed and also not opened in one place <Card>